# Problem Setting Up a Network Bridge for OpenVPN Server

Tags: openvpn, network-bridge

I've installed bridge-utils and have followed several articles for creating DHCP to my LAN with OpenVPN. It appears that I have bridge set up correctly but when I start OpenVPN server I get this message:

tap0: Could not generate persistent MAC: No data available

Can someone help me troubleshoot this? TIA.